# Mandatory CVS Comments in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cvs

Quite an easy question but could not find the answer I'm looking for.

Can anyone please tell me if it is possible to make the comment(text area) mandatory when promoting something to CVS from eclipse?

I struggle to remember to do it and you can not edit a commit to change the comment afterwards, so all I want is for a message to pop up saying "Please insert a comment before committing" when I try to commit without capturing the comment.

I'm a front end developer so step by step instructions would be amazing!

Thank you.

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but the easiest way to do it it by enforcing it on the CVS server as a [pre commit hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857101/use-the-commit-message-in-a-cvs-pre-commit-hook).